# JQuery Mobile fieldset options can be seen under control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i'm trying to build a interface with jquery mobile but the option buttons can be seen under the controls. How can i make the disappear?

```html
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="time-period-type">
    <input type="radio" name="time-period" id="weekly-time-period" value="weekly" checked="checked">
    <label for="weekly-time-period">WEEKS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="time-period" id="monthly-time-period" value="monthly">
    <label for="monthly-time-period">MONTHS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="time-period" id="yearly-time-period" value="yearly">
    <label for="yearly-time-period">YEARS</label>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#time-period-type > input{
  display      :  none;
  //opacity    :  0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="time-period-type">
    <input type="radio" name="time-period" id="weekly-time-period" value="weekly" checked="checked">
    <label for="weekly-time-period">WEEKS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="time-period" id="monthly-time-period" value="monthly">
    <label for="monthly-time-period">MONTHS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="time-period" id="yearly-time-period" value="yearly">
    <label for="yearly-time-period">YEARS</label>
</fieldset>
```

set `display : none` to your input element or else add `opacity :0`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Works perfectly!